# Scripting in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

I'm quite new for ElasticSearch and absolutely newbie in Kibana and was a little bit confused:
Doc says that for Kibana 4 we could use advanced scripting in queries, but with later update that groovy is currently disabled.

My question is: is it possible to make advanced queries in Kibana 4.5's Discovery, using some logic, like checking array field's size?

Am I right that search field in Discovery tab is only accepting URI search, which is limited in options?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can created scripted fields in Kibana which will compute the results at run time.

You can use any of the fields present and use those fields to create dynamic fields such as addition of 2 numeric fields etc.

You can create a scripted field by :

1. Clicking on Settings Tab
2. Click on the Index name (present in Left side).

You will now get list of fields on the right.

3. Click on Scripted Fields Tab which is beside Fields tab.
4. Click on Add Scripted field to add scripted fields.

Example to add 2 numbers,Create a scripted field with following expression:

doc['field1'].value + doc['field2'].value